# I need to know most cost effective way to allow users to update their info in Salesforce

Tags: discussion, support

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for Sales Stack Exchange, so here's a preview before I attempt to post it.

My client doesn't have the budget for Salesforce Communities. They need to allow their vendors to login, update their address info, status, and skill sets. Communities will obviously allow for this, but not cost effective for them. I noticed there is still Salesforce Sites, but I need to allow user logins. Say they need 1,000 users to be able to login and update their information and status, is Sites a less expensive option?

I want to avoid writing a .Net application and going through the API, or similar approach.

Is this question appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to find out about pricing information is to contact the Account Executive or Sales. From a "ballpark" perspective, Sites is probably less expensive, but also has restrictions on what type of data you can expose to those types of licenses. Also, if Salesforce Communities is too expensive, you might simply look into the limited login licenses, which are less expensive. However, how much you'll save, and if it will suit your needs, is only something the account executive can definitely answer. Also, a question of this type will likely be outdated far quicker than a question about even a beta feature, as the pricing matrix is updated frequently.